# Do I need a Transit Visa if i change my flight at Dubai

Tags: transit

Suppose I am going to Delhi from Bahrain and by diffrent airlines , and at Dubai airport I collect my luggage and again went to immigration for boarding my next flight . Do i required transit visa in this scenerio

Comment: What nationality (or nationalities) do you hold?

Answer (score 0):

In case you plan on waiting in the transit zone, you won"t need it. But if the transit time is quite long and you wish to exit the transit zone for a time, you should get it.

Update : 
For your case, you probably shall ask your airline, but I guess you'd have to get that transit visa.

Comment: The OP plans to collect their luggage from the baggage claim, which will require passing immigration and leaving the transit zone.